# can't install ubuntu along with windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

respected person

I have an laptop hp pavilion g6-2312 ax,runs windows 8.1(uefi boot loader)
actually wanted to install ubuntu along with windows 8.1 and came to know that ubuntu runs on mbr and don't have that type of partition table on my pc I had even tried to load ubuntu on external hard drive but does not loads at all after installation
it doesn't show that there is any operating system already on the hard drive to install it along win 8.1

if i try to install grub, it doesn't load windows 8.1 ....please help me so that it can be useful

Answer (score 0):

First, mbr is a small program that gets loaded after the BIOS finishes. Its job is to load the operating system. Windows OSes installs mbr in the first sector of the hard disk.

A lot of people have problems getting an external drive to boot their computer, and I don't know enough to help with that issue.

Ubuntu uses either ext3 or ext4 format for the partition. You can install Ubuntu on your drive by making room for it. You will need to shrink the Windows partition to make space using a Partition Manager. When you install Ubuntu, it will load GRUB2 (a program similar to mbr). When GRUB2 is installed, the drive is scanned for bootable partitions and the information is written on the drive so that the menu has a list of all bootable partitions.

Answer (score 0):

In some laptops namely HP after you install Ubuntu os while it boots go press F9 for selection of boot device. It will show you some options
 e.g. os manager, USB stick and Netbook hard drive. 
Select **Netbook hard Drive** there it will show you os list for ubuntu.